# Skill rating with varying amount of coins per game

Tags: rating-system

I have implemented [**ELO rating**](https://mattmazzola.medium.com/understanding-the-elo-rating-system-264572c7a2b4) for matchmaking, similar to the implementation of [BoardGameArena](https://en.boardgamearena.com/faq?anchor=faq_account_elo).  This works great, matching players with about the same rating.

However the system is vulnerable to abuse. This is because in my games players play using virtual coins, they choose how much to bid on each game. Bids varying from 1 to 1000 coins.  Thus, a player can intentionally lose games at low bids to reduce his rating, and then play on the high bids with easier matching.

**How can I fix this vulnerability?**

1. record ELO rating for buckets of bid sizes.
2. use `K = f(coins)`, which mean that the ELO change at the game's end depends on how many coins were played.

Comment: Is it an option just to restrict the maximum bid at lower ELOs?

Comment: Why not include how much ELO you gain/ loose in relation to how many coins were bet?

Comment: @Zibelas, are you saying to set K = number of coins that were bet?

Comment: @Cohensius Well, make K = f(coins) where f is a monotonically increasing function; it doesn't necessarily have to be a straight equality.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think allowing the players to control how much rating a player can gain or lose will allow for a lot more gaming then just basing it on wins and losses. If they are playing against someone they have a strong possibility of winning they bid more, if against someone they can't beat for some reason the bid little.

Comment: @JoeW Depends if the bid selection is made before or after knowing your opponent?

Comment: I would just hid the ELO of the opponent till after the bid are made

Comment: @PhilipKendall That is true but I still don't think that it is a good idea to let the players have such a large impact on how much ratings can change.

Comment: @Styxsksu Everything about the opponent would need to be hidden so that nothing is known before the bid.

Comment: @JoeW, right but it is not a problem since the player chooses the bid before the matchmaking is made.  Players do not choose their opponents.

Comment: Maybe I am reading your question wrong but you seem to think that there is a problem because players could throw low value matches to slightly lower their rating. My concern is that when you give players a way to manipulate the system they will do so in ways that you likely won't think of when designing it.

Comment: @JoeW, you are right.  This is the reason that I am consulting with you guys.

Comment: I think the simplest option is to tie the bets into the ELO calculation. This can actually be done rather easily with ELO, I think. Just multiply the ELO gain by a weight proportional to the number of coins bet on that game.

Comment: @Stef, not sure this is a good idea since the difference in bets is huge (from 1 to 1000).  So say a game of bet=1 will use a K=1, and a game of a 1000 a K=1000.  K of 1000 is absurd.  

If a game of a 1000 uses a K<1000 then the system is still vulnerable to "lose many 1 games then play on 1000"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Rather than using a standard ELO, use the net number of coins a player has won as the measure of their skill.

If the goal is to prevent players from artificially lowering their ranking to gain coins, then tie their ranking to the number of coins they have.  While abuse is still possible to a limited extent, it's capped at the number of coins you can earn in a single game, because as soon as they start to have any success with their plan, their ranking rises.  It's a self-correcting system, just like a good ELO system.

If you want to aggressively encourage players to pair against people of the same skill level, then set up a ratio system in the bidding, so that one coin from a player who has very few coins matches ten coins from a player with many coins when bidding - this discourages players from playing against those with significantly fewer coins (because the rewards are less and the risks are higher), and means the players who do well against higher-ranked players will advance quickly.  This mimics the ELO system of scaling rating changes based on opponent's strength.

Coins gained from alternative methods (buying coins with real-world money, promotions, etc) shouldn't be factored into the ranking, only coins "earned" during play.

Comment: Love your answer.  I think that it fits best to my scenario because I care more about the coins economy and less about exactly ranking the players by skill.